# Conflict between siunitx and mathenv?

Tags: packages, incompatibility

I have a problem when I use 'siunitx' and 'mathenv' together.

I wanted to add 'siunitx' to use '\meter' and so one but it seems to have a problem with 'mathenv' :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    % Mathématiques
\usepackage{mathenv}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\title{Test}
\author{Cécile Moulin}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

text text text
\end{document}
```

gives the following error :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdwtools/mathenv.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdwtools/mdwtab.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-
mappings.tex))) (./test.aux)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.13 \begin{document}
```

Comment: The `mathenv` package hasn't be maintained for almost two decades.

Comment: From the readme (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdwtools) `Contains a collection of mathematical environments with a theme of aligning things in columns.` Maybe it's better to check out the famous`amsmath` package or `mathtools` (builds on `amsmath`) package which also provide alignment options.

Comment: @egreg I don't even remember why I use this package... Is there a way to know ?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I use this package to. I didn't put it in the example because it is not a part of the error. But as I said, I don't remember why I used mathenv...

A last question, how do you write the package's name here ? I tried with '' but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Ccile The simplest way is to comment its call and look at what happens.

Comment: @egreg I did and nothing... I suppose I don't use it. Maybe in another version.

Comment: The name for the symbol for the `formatting`is `Accent grave`. I have tp press Shift plus a key on my German keyboard on order to type it.

Comment: If you don't know why you are using a package, don't use it and wait for an error message.  If you don't get one, celebrate!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was caused by loading an unnecessary package